# Removing html tags inside url tags

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

How to remove from all links `<strong>` tags inside URL elements:

```
 <a href="http://www.customlink.it" target="_blank"><strong>Text</strong></a>
```

with this:

```
 <a href="http://www.customlink.it" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublimetext supports regex (I don't know about notepad++). You should be able to use this :

Find : `<a (.+?)><strong>(.+?)</strong></a>`
Replace : `<a \1>\2</a>`

If you meant remove them from your file (I see you tagged your question `notepad++` and `sublime text`)